# Books dealing with Quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a complete book for quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8441/what-is-a-complete-book-for-quantum-field-theory)

I am looking for good books that deal with Quantum Field theory starting from basics. Please suggest something that deals with the physical interpretation of the subject, and not just the mathematical formalism. Books dealing with particle sources and particle detectors will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your description suggests you may try Anthony Zee's textbook. See the list at http://motls.blogspot.com/2006/01/qft-didactics.html?m=1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451

Comment: Does any one know of any Clear expositions of particle Sources and detectors

Comment: [This](http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter1.pdf) is a nice source.