# Functional integral aproach for Feynman rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral, feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

I am familiar with the basic ideas of quantum field theory but I feel uncomfortable when I have to derive Feynman rules by myself for a given action  (for example in non-linear sigma models or electrodynamics). Could you provide a list of good books, articles, lecture notes and/or any other sources (except Peskin), where Wick's theorem and the Feynman rules are derived from the functional integral **in detail**, preferably with examples?

Comment: If you'd prefer a more systematic approach using the path integral for gauge theories, I suggest you research the Faddeev-Popov method. A good source to start you off is Srednicki's textbook.

Comment: See http://www.perimeterscholars.org/home.html, course: Quantum Field Theory II, from 11/12 to 13/14 for a treatment of the path integral. The last lectures of the course focus on the Faddeev-Popov approach.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 and links therein.