# Book recommendation relating QFT in statistical physics and particle physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, wick-rotation

I know that QFT is heavily used in statistical physics but, as a former particle physicists, I search a book that would nicely bridge the two different perspectives, especially when it comes to the renormalisation group, since both communities use essentially the same formalism but from very different viewpoints, as far as I understand. Any recommendation? Graduate-level is fine, or I guess compulsory! I did go through the various recommendations question related to QFT but I haven't find any clear fit to my particular question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a complete book for quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/)

Comment: You quote me a page that does not even contain the word statistical. I mean, yes, I could check all the book on QFT ever cited on this site but that I would need to do that validates my question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently reading Zinn Justin's quantum field theory and critical phenomena and I really like the fact he treats quantum and statistical fields in one swoop. His approach is very systematic and I really like it. I can't comment on his treatment of RG, but if it is similar  to the rest, it should be good.  kardar statistical physics of fields has a slightly more statistical bent but I find it very concise.  It might be good for you though because you already understand RG from a high energy perspective.

Comment: I had a look at the table of content and it alternates between statistical physics and particle physics several times. Moreover it covers huge swath of both fields. This looks exactly what I was searching for! Thank  you.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you want a more self-contained and less encyclopedic treatment, I highly recommend his other book "Phase Transitions and the Renormalization Group."  There's a  fair amount of overlap with "Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena."