# Good book on quantum field theory to start learning as an undergraduate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a book to study QFT in my vacations. I have all the standard maths on an undergraduate physics program level plus a little of group theory.

I found very good reviews from Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur, although there are a few harsh criticism. I was thinking to buy this book, but found to better to have some advice of more experienced physicists in the subject, given that books are really expensive from where I live. So, is it worth as a first book? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a complete book for quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/)

Comment: I would personally suggest 'QFT and the Standard Model' by Schwartz as a first book on QFT which caters for students from a wide range of backgrounds.