# Interpretation on a propagation amplitude in (3.93) of Peskin's QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, causality, propagator, s-matrix-theory

From page. 55 and (3.93) of Peskin and Schroeder's *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*:

> First consider the propagation amplitude $\langle 0|\psi(x) \bar{\psi}(y)|0 \rangle$, which is to represent a positive-energy particle propagating from $y$ to $x$. In this case we want the (Heisenberg) state $\bar{\psi}(y)|0 \rangle$ to be made up of only positive-energy, or negative-frequency components (since a Heisenberg state $\Psi_H=e^{+iHt}\Psi_S$).

### My questions are ---

1. In this form $$\langle 0|\psi(x) \bar{\psi}(y)|0 \rangle \sim \langle 0| a_p e^{-ipx}  a_q^\dagger e^{ i q y}|0 \rangle$$

It is said to take out only

- negative frequency and positive energy component for $a_q^\dagger e^{ i q y}|0 \rangle$.
- positive frequency and positive energy component for $ a_p e^{-ipx} ...$

I do not fully understand what is the emphasis here? Is  the interpretation here that we only select the positive energy component or state, for a reason?

How about the negative frequency and positive frequency parts? Why does the interpretation  of
negative frequency and positive frequency matter?

2. How is this calculation a resolution of the negative energy problem?

---

Precisely from this paragraph:

[image]

p.s. I found a related but also unsolved post here just now when I am posting myself: [Sign of energy and frequency in a propagation amplitude](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382087/42982)