# Mathematical bases/prerequisites for Feynman's "QED"

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, education, mathematics

I have enjoyed studying Feynman's book "QED". I have sufficient mathematical maturity to go beyond his analogies. I am hoping someone has provided notes on the book enumerating the mathematical basis for his analogies and images.

Comment: There are a large number of books that cover the mathematics of quantum field theory to the point where you can then perform QED calculations and understand what Feynman diagrams really represent. As far as I know, there are no notes specifically elaborating on this particular nontechnical book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a complete book for introductory quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/)

Comment: OK, thanks. I have access to textbooks, and I guess I'll just have to figure it all out.