# Book reference: Quantum field theory from path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral

a) What are some good references to learn quantum field theory from the approach of path integrals? Like books which start from path integral formulation of quantum mechanics and then do calculations using path integral approach.

b) Also, what are some good books to learn non-relativistic field theory?

Comment: To a) i can really recommend Ryder, which really goes onto path integrals, especially in calculations

Comment: possible dup.? [What is a complete book for introductory quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/84967).

Comment: DeWitt really commits to path integrals. To some extent, so does Zinn-Justin.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I saw your answer in the link provided above but it does not specifically mention path integral approach. Hence I asked this. Any suggestions for non-relativistic field theory?

Comment: @abhijit975 Yes: don't waste your time. Do relativistic FT only. You're welcome.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, any reason why not?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk I was just joking. I guess tone does not transmit well through typing.

Comment: You can refer "Field Theory: A Path Integral Approach" by Ashok Das