# QFT and Standard Model Book Help Please

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, standard-model, education

I'm sure that questions of this ilk have been asked before however I wanted to know if there is some advice for someone from my background. Recently, I've taught myself General Relativity (needed to fill time during lockdown, eh?), reading pretty much cover to cover 'Spacetime and Geometry' (Carroll) and coming up to finishing 'General Relativity' (Wald) in the same fashion, and I intend to read 'Large-Scale Structures of Space-time' (Hawking and Ellis) after. I'd really like to catch up on the Quantum aspect of everything, though.

Context is, I'm a maths student and have covered a good deal of QM (although doing rel has made me a little rusty...) so I'd quite like to read something that doesn't really beat around the bush mathematically. I was wondering if there's anything that covers QFT and the Standard Model that's of similar difficulty to Wald in the context of GR, if that makes sense? I appreciate all help - the topic seems to be massive and I don't know what the 'industry standard' textbooks for this area are!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a complete book for introductory quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/)

Comment: Check this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Thank you both for these, they seem great links. The issue is, there are so many to choose from (which I'm grateful for!) I was wondering what is considered 'if you're going to read a QFT book, it's this one:' type book though. But it, naturally, doesn't seem as straightforward as that

Comment: Hi @lloydy.99, I think that selecting just one book goes against the spirit of [resource-recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/149907). The purpose of those questions is to provide substantial answers which explain the style, content, and prerequisites of the book so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others. In most cases, there is not a single authoritative reference.